# Clang optimizations change the result of calculations in C even when I add explicit type casting

Tags: c, optimization, casting, clang

I noticed that the code below compiled with clang 11.0.3 gives different result when I use -O0 and -O3 flag.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t foo(int64_t a, int32_t b, int32_t c) {
    const int32_t p1 = 7654321;
    const int32_t p2 = 8765432;
    const int64_t p3 = 1234567LL;
    const int32_t p4 = 987654;
    const int64_t e = a + b * b * p1 + b * p2 + c * c * p3 + c * p4; 
    return e;
}

int main(void) {
    const int64_t a = 1234LL;
    int32_t b = 130;
    int32_t c = -148;
    printf("%lld\n", foo(a, b, c)); // -O0: 28544296190, -O3: 28544296190
    b = 167;
    c = -93;
    printf("%lld\n", foo(a, b, c)); // -O0: 10772740108, -O3: 15067707404
    return 0;
}
```

First result is the same however the second one differs. I thought it happens because of implicit type conversion. I compiled the code to assembly with -O0 flag to see in what order all computations are performed. According to that I added explicit casting and parenthesis in function foo:

```
const int64_t e = (((a + (int64_t)(b * b * p1)) + (int64_t)(b * p2)) + (int64_t)((int64_t)(c * c) * p3)) + (int64_t)(c * p4);
```

This did not help though and I really do not know how to fix it. How the code should look like in order to work properly with O3 optimizations?

Comment: You have to cast an *operand* to force bigger arithmetic. `(b * b * p1)` might have *already* overflowed, and casting after the multiplication isn't going to stop it. So `(int64_t)(b * b * p1)` needs to be `((int64_t)b * b * p1)` The cast does not tell how to do the arithmetic, just what the operand is to be, and that is what decides the arithmetic (for values bigger than `int` – smaller types get promoted to `int` automatically).

Comment: I replaced all the types in your program with `double` to see what the real answers are. They are 157393315070 and 225521104908, which don't match any of the answers that you got. Conclusion: your code has signed integer overflow, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: When optimizations change your program's observable behavior, it's usually because you have Undefined Behavior somewhere. Had you compiled with `clang -fsanitize=undefined`, your program would have told you exactly what the problem was: `example.c:9:33: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 16900 * 7654321 cannot be represented in type 'int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got overflow here:

```
 b * b * p1
```

When `b` is 167, you first have (int32_t)167 * (int32_t)167 == (int32_t)27889.  Then you have (int32_t)27889 * (int32_t)7654321 == 213471358369‬ which is outside the range of a signed 32 bit integer.  Overflow on signed integers invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which clang apparently exploited at `-O3`.

The casting you did wasn't sufficient because the cast was applied *after* the overflow occurred.  You need to add the cast to at least the first operand of each multiplication so that all operands are converted to `int64_t`.

```
const int64_t e = a + (int64_t)b * b * p1 + (int64_t)b * p2 + (int64_t)c * c * p3 + (int64_t)c * p4;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought signed integers always wrap like unsigned integers. Nevertheless, wrapping is something I actually expected here because I port some code from java where, as far as I know, integers wrap.